# Properly scaling marginal drop caps

Tags: typography, drop-cap

Can anyone suggest a reasonably generalisable way to generate these marginal drop caps?

The key features are that

- the drop cap may be more than one glyph long
- its width is scaled to fill the margin (minus a bit of white space for legibility)
- its height is scaled to a user-specified whole number of lines (nb. the first example spans five lines and the second four).

[image]

[image]

Comment: @campa's answer does what you ask but I don't think you want that, I think you should scale to the number of lines (chosen so it more or less fills the margin). Distorting the letters to then exactly fill the margin seems a step too far.  As long as you right align towards the text it is not reaslly discernable if the space to the left of the C is exact;y the same as the space to the left of the A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you should deform the letters to force them to be exactly the line height and exactly margin width, scale to match the line height, and just choose the number of lines so the width is about right.

Note getting good line breaks are tricky, I don't know which is the original but some typographer at some point has adjusted between "five thousand" and "5000" and between "and" and "&" and perhaps other changes, to make things fit nicely (comparing your image with the text at Gutenberg press);

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern,graphicx,color}
\setlength\textwidth{7.2cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\emergencystretch{1em}
% text from
% https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1051/1051-h/1051-h.htm

\begin{document}

\noindent\llap{%
\smash{\raisebox{-4\baselineskip}{\resizebox{!}{4.7\baselineskip}{\color{red}{\Huge C}}}}%
\kern-1pt}%
\MakeUppercase{onsidering our present
%advanced
advanct
state of culture, and how the Torch
of Science has now been brandished and borne about, with more or less
effect, for 
%five thousand
5000 % sic
 years}
%
% and
\&
upwards; how, in these times
especially, not only the Torch still burns, and perhaps more fiercely
than ever, but innumerable Rushlights, and Sulphur-matches, kindled
thereat, are also glancing in every direction, so that not the
smallest cranny or dog-hole in Nature or Art can remain
unilluminated,—it might strike the reflective mind with some surprise
that hitherto little or nothing of a fundamental character, whether in
the way of Philosophy or History, has been written on the subject of
Clothes.
\P\ %
Our Theory of Gravitation is as good as perfect: Lagrange, it is well
known, has proved that the Planetary System, on this scheme, will
endure forever; Laplace, still more cunningly, even guesses that it
could not have been made on any other scheme. Whereby, at least, our
nautical Logbooks can be better kept; and water-transport of all kinds
has grown more commodious. Of Geology and Geognosy we know enough:
what with the labors of our Werners and Huttons, what with the ardent
genius of their disciples, it has come about that now, to many a Royal
Society, the Creation of a World is little more mysterious than the
cooking of a dumpling; concerning which last, indeed, there have been
minds to whom the question, How the apples were got in, presented
difficulties. Why mention our disquisitions on the Social Contract, on
the Standard of Taste, on the Migrations of the Herring? Then, have we
not a Doctrine of Rent, a Theory of Value; Philosophies of Language,
of History, of Pottery, of Apparitions, of Intoxicating Liquors? Man's
whole life and environment have been laid open and elucidated;
scarcely a fragment or fibre of his Soul, Body, and Possessions, but
has been probed, dissected, distilled, desiccated, and scientifically
decomposed: our spiritual Faculties, of which it appears there are not
a few, have their

\clearpage




\noindent\llap{%
\smash{\raisebox{-3\baselineskip}{\resizebox{!}{3.7\baselineskip}{\color{red}{\Huge A\kern-3pt S}}}}%
\kern-1pt}%
\MakeUppercase{a wonder-loving}
%
\& 
and wonder-seeking man, Teufelsdrockh, from an
early part of this Clothes-Volume, has more and more exhibited
himself. Striking it was, amid all his perverse cloudiness, with what
force of vision and of heart he pierced into the mystery of the World;
recognizing in the highest sensible phenomena, so far as Sense went,
only fresh or faded Raiment; yet ever, under this, a celestial Essence
thereby rendered visible: and while, on the one hand, he trod the old
rags of Matter, with their tinsels, into the mire, he on the other
everywhere exalted Spirit above all earthly principalities and powers,
and worshipped it, though under the meanest shapes, with a true
Platonic mysticism. What the man ultimately purposed by thus casting
his Greek-fire into the general Wardrobe of the Universe; what such,
more or less complete, rending and burning of Garments throughout the
whole compass of Civilized Life and Speculation, should lead to; the
rather as he was no Adamite, in any sense, and could not, like
Rousseau, recommend either bodily or intellectual Nudity, and a return
to the savage state: all this our readers are now bent to discover;
this is, in fact, properly the gist and purport of Professor
Teufelsdrockh's Philosophy of Clothes.
\P\ %
Be it remembered, however, that such purport is here not so much
evolved, as detected to lie ready for evolving. We are to guide our
British Friends into the new Gold-country, and show them the mines;
nowise to dig out and exhaust its wealth, which indeed remains for all
time inexhaustible. Once there, let each dig for his own behoof, and
enrich himself.
\P\ %
Neither, in so capricious inexpressible a Work as this of the
Professor's, can our course now more than formerly be straightforward,
step by step, but at best leap by leap. Significant Indications stand
out here and there; which for the critical eye, that looks both widely
and narrowly, shape themselves into some ground-scheme of a Whole: to
select these with judgment, so that a leap from one to the other be
possible, and (in our old figure) by chaining them together, a
passable Bridge be effected: this, as heretofore, continues our only
method. Among such light-spots, the following, floating in much wild
matter about Perfectibility, has seemed worth clutching at:—

"Perhaps the most remarkable incident in Modern History," says
Teufelsdrockh, "is not the Diet of Worms, still less the Battle of
Austerlitz, Waterloo, Peterloo, or any other Battle; but an incident
passed carelessly over by most Historians, and treated with some
degree of ridicule by others: namely, George Fox's making to himself a
suit of Leather. This man, the first of the Quakers, and by trade a
Shoemaker, was one of those, to whom, under ruder or purer form, the
Divine Idea of the Universe is pleased to manifest itself; and, across
all the hulls of Ignorance and earthly Degradation, shine through, in
unspeakable Awfulness, unspeakable Beauty, on their souls: who
therefore are rightly accounted Prophets, God-possessed; or even Gods,
as in some periods it has chanced. Sitting in his stall; working on
tanned hides, amid pincers, paste-horns, rosin, swine-bristles, and a
nameless flood of rubbish, this youth had, nevertheless, a Living
Spirit belonging to him; also an antique Inspired Volume, through
which, as through a window, it could look upwards, and discern its
celestial Home. The task of a daily pair of shoes, coupled even with
some prospect of victuals, and an honorable Mastership in Cordwainery,
and perhaps the post of Thirdborough in his hundred, as the crown of
long faithful sewing,—was nowise satisfaction enough to such a mind:
but ever amid the boring and hammering came tones from that far
country, came Splendors and Terrors; for this poor Cordwainer, as we
said, was a Man; and the Temple of Immensity, wherein as Man he had
been sent to minister, was full of holy mystery to him.

"The Clergy of the neighborhood, the ordained Watchers and
Interpreters of that same holy mystery, listened with un-affected
tedium to his consultations, and advised him, as the solution of such
doubts, to 'drink beer, and dance with the girls.' Blind leaders of
the blind! For what end were their tithes levied and eaten; for what
were their shovel-hats scooped out, and their surplices and
cassock-aprons girt on; and such a church-repairing, and chaffering,
and organing, and other racketing, held over that spot of God's
Earth,—if Man were but a Patent Digester, and the Belly with its
adjuncts the grand Reality? Fox turned from them, with tears and a
sacred scorn, back to his Leather-parings and his Bible. Mountains of
encumbrance, higher than AEtna, had been heaped over that Spirit: but
it was a Spirit, and would not lie buried there. Through long days and
nights of silent agony, it struggled and wrestled, with a man's force,
to be free: how its prison-mountains heaved and swayed tumultuously,
as the giant spirit shook them to this hand and that, and emerged into
the light of Heaven! That Leicester shoe-shop, had men known it, was a
holier place than any Vatican or Loretto-shrine.—'So bandaged, and
hampered, and hemmed in,' groaned he, 'with thousand requisitions,
obligations, straps, tatters, and tagrags, I can neither see nor move:
not my own am I, but the World's; and Time flies fast, and Heaven is
high, and Hell is deep: Man! bethink thee, if thou hast power of
Thought! Why not; what binds me here? Want, want!—Ha, of what? Will
all the shoe-wages under the Moon ferry me across into that far Land
of Light? Only Meditation can, and devout Prayer to God. I will to the
woods: the hollow of a tree will lodge me, wild berries feed me; and
for Clothes, cannot I stitch myself one perennial suit of Leather!'

"Historical Oil-painting," continues Teufelsdrockh, "is one of the
Arts I never practiced; therefore shall I not decide whether this
subject were easy of execution on the canvas. Yet often has it seemed
to me as if such first outflashing of man's Freewill, to lighten, more
and more into Day, the Chaotic Night that threatened to engulf him in
its hindrances and its horrors, were properly the only grandeur there
is in History. Let some living Angelo or Rosa, with seeing eye and
understanding heart, picture George Fox on that morning, when he
spreads out his cutting-board for the last time, and cuts cowhides by
unwonted patterns, and stitches them together into one continuous
all-including Case, the farewell service of his awl! Stitch away, thou
noble Fox: every prick of that little instrument is pricking into the
heart of Slavery, and World-worship, and the Mammon-god. Thy elbows
jerk, as in strong swimmer-strokes, and every stroke is bearing thee
across the Prison-ditch, within which Vanity holds her Workhouse and
Ragfair, into lands of true Liberty; were the work done, there is in
broad Europe one Free Man, and thou art he!

"Thus from the lowest depth there is a path to the loftiest height;
and for the Poor also a Gospel has been published. Surely if, as
D'Alembert asserts, my illustrious namesake, Diogenes, was the
greatest man of Antiquity, only that he wanted Decency, then by
stronger reason is George Fox the greatest of the Moderns, and greater
than Diogenes himself: for he too stands on the adamantine basis of
his Manhood, casting aside all props and shoars; yet not, in
half-savage Pride, undervaluing the Earth; valuing it rather, as a
place to yield him warmth and food, he looks Heavenward from his
Earth, and dwells in an element of Mercy and Worship, with a still
Strength, such as the Cynic's Tub did nowise witness. Great, truly,
was that Tub; a temple from which man's dignity and divinity was
scornfully preached abroad: but greater is the Leather Hull, for the
same sermon was preached there, and not in Scorn but in Love."

George Fox's "perennial suit," with all that it held, has been worn
quite into ashes for nigh two centuries: why, in a discussion on the
Perfectibility of Society, reproduce it now? Not out of blind
sectarian partisanship: Teufelsdrockh, himself is no Quaker; with all
his pacific tendencies, did not we see him, in that scene at the North
Cape, with the Archangel Smuggler, exhibit fire-arms?

For us, aware of his deep Sansculottism, there is more meant in this
passage than meets the ear. At the same time, who can avoid smiling at
the earnestness and Boeotian simplicity (if indeed there be not an
underhand satire in it), with which that "Incident" is here brought
forward; and, in the Professor's ambiguous way, as clearly perhaps as
he durst in Weissnichtwo, recommended to imitation! Does Teufelsdrockh
anticipate that, in this age of refinement, any considerable class of
the community, by way of testifying against the "Mammon-god," and
escaping from what he calls "Vanity's Workhouse and Ragfair," where
doubtless some of them are toiled and whipped and hoodwinked
sufficiently,—will sheathe themselves in close-fitting cases of
Leather? The idea is ridiculous in the extreme. Will Majesty lay aside
its robes of state, and Beauty its frills and train-gowns, for a
second skin of tanned hide? By which change Huddersfield and
Manchester, and Coventry and Paisley, and the Fancy-Bazaar, were
reduced to hungry solitudes; and only Day and Martin could profit. For
neither would Teufelsdrockh's mad daydream, here as we presume
covertly intended, of levelling Society (levelling it indeed with a
vengeance, into one huge drowned marsh!), and so attaining the
political effects of Nudity without its frigorific or other
consequences,—be thereby realized. Would not the rich man purchase a
waterproof suit of Russia Leather; and the high-born Belle step forth
in red or azure morocco, lined with shamoy: the black cowhide being
left to the Drudges and Gibeonites of the world; and so all the old
Distinctions be re-established?

Or has the Professor his own deeper intention; and laughs in his
sleeve at our strictures and glosses, which indeed are but a part
thereof?




\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree that in the end the deformed letterforms aren't great (the originals from the Doves Press were engraved by hand by Edward Johnston). It seems that the equivalent modern solution would be to hand-draw the initial capitals as vector artwork, and that might be the only good way to get close to the same result.

Comment: @Ubiquitous you are saying my `\kern-3pt` between A and S doesn't have the flair and typographic artistry of Johnston's engravings? I'm shocked and disappointed:-)

Comment: If it's any consolation, I have it on good authority that, when it comes to LaTeX, Johnston has nothing on you.